# Find last 30 occurrences of a string in a log file using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a log file which is being populated every 30 seconds. I need to find the last 30 occurrences of a string (i.e. after every 15 minutes). After that, I need to save them in an array.

The string is of the form `(55.89)K/s`. What regular expression should be used for this?

Also, since lock will be there on the file (it is being written at that time), can Perl still do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find the last 30 occurrences of a string (i.e. after every
>   15 minutes). After that, I need to save them in an array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;

my $fname = 'mylog.log';

open my $LOGFILE, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname for reading: $!";

my $text;

{
    local $/ = undef;
    $text = <$LOGFILE>;
}

my $regex = qr{
    [(]  
    \d\d
    [.]
    \d\d
    [)]
    K/s
}xms;

my @matches = ($text =~ /$regex/g);

my $n = 2;
my @last_n_matches = @matches[-$n..-1];
say for @last_n_matches;

--output:--
(22.22)K/s
(33.33)K/s
```

To execute a perl script every n minutes, see here:

http://perlmaven.com/how-to-run-a-perl-script-automatciall-every

> Also, since lock will be there on the file (it is being written at
>   that time), can Perl still do this for me?

Yes.  Locks are only observed by code that bothers to check for them.  However, if you don't wait for the lock to open, then if something is writing one of your numbers to the log file at the same time your perl code slurps the file, then you could end up with half the number, which means the regex won't match, and you'll miss that number.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `grep` and `tail`:

```
grep '\(\d+\.\d+\)K/s' | tail -30
```

Here is a way to do this with  Perl:

```
use Modern::Perl;
my @log;
open my $fh, '<', "/path/to/logfile";
while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    push @log, $_ if /\(\d+\.\d+\)K\/s/;
}
say for @log[-30 .. -1];
```